# Starting an executable with a custom configuration file

Tags: c#, dosbox

I am working on a simple C# project that calls for me to launch a program, pointing it at a custom configuration file.  Specifically, I'm launching DOSBox with a custom config file that tells it what to do upon starting.  I've used shortcuts before, and essentially this is what I put in the shortcut and it works perfectly.

```
"D:\Video Game Emulation\DOSBox\DOSBox.exe" "D:\Video Game Emulation\DOS Windows\GAMES\CUSTOM.CONF"
```

Now the program I'm writing is just a prettier way of launching a bunch of old DOS games through DOSBox, each with their own custom config.  So in my button code, here's what I have.

```
Process.Start("D:\\Video Game Emulation\\DOSBox\\DOSBox.exe", "D:\\Video Game Emulation\\DOS Windows\\GAMES\\CUSTOM.CONF");
```

According to my understanding that is the proper way to start an executable and give it a custom option.  However, that launches just fine, but doesn't pass in the config file properly.  I also tried this.

```
Process.Start("D:\\Video Game Emulation\\DOSBox\\DOSBox.exe", -conf "D:\\Video Game Emulation\\DOS Windows\\GAMES\\CUSTOM.CONF");
```

With no luck either.  Anyone know what I need to change in order for it to give DOSBox the custom configuration file properly?

Comment: Have you tried using the StartInfo on the Process Object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, sorry it has taken so long to get back to this thread, but I've been quite busy.  Thanks to help from dakre18, StarPilot, and Bearcat9428 I figured it out.  **It seems that the working directory has to be specified in the StartInfo in order for it to work**.  Things seem to work now.  Thanks for all your help everyone!

Answer (score 0):

Pass in the path as a string, so put your quotation marks in and test it.

Basically the reason is when checking Intellisense (spelling?), it shows an overload for Start(string fileName, string arguments).

So it wouldn't hurt to make sure you are passing strings into both.

Edit:  I think I may have seen it before you edited your post.  Did you have the quotation marks in the code?

Comment: I added them shortly after posting, when I realized I needed them.  I had them when testing it but forgot them when I typed up my post.

Comment: What about putting the -conf for the argument inside the second quotation marks?

Comment: Just tried it.  No luck.  Also tried it like this: 

"-conf 'D:\\Video Game Emulation\\DOS Windows\\GAMES\\CUSTOM.CONF'"

Comment: Well it looks like it should definitely be in the string if you use it, but otherwise the only thing i can think that would help is to start with some basic troubleshooting of which part isn't working.  So lets say if you use only the file path, it should work, then the easiest argument is -fullscreen and see if that works.  My guess is there is either a problem passing arguments, or it's doing something unexpected like closing immediately after opening.

Comment: Just tried it with "-fullscreen" as the only argument.  It works fine.  

BTW even when pointing it at a configuration file path, it starts and runs fine, but it loads the default configuration instead of the one I'm trying to point it at.

Comment: Hmm, then it sounds like it may be a permissions issue, which sounds odd, because you should have full admin access already.  Just because Windows is picky (I've seen some dumb fixes), try taking the compiled program and run as an administrator and see if that makes a difference.  The arguments are getting passed right, but it sounds like it can't load the config file.  So lets assume the Windows fix didn't work, then i'm stumped on that.  My only suggestion from there is to either create a new file and/or stick the config in the project folder as part of the program and try running it.

Comment: Well this IS interesting.  Running it as administrator didn't help, but putting the file right into the program folder did work.  So it has to be something about the path that it isn't liking.  The double slashes are there because C# was getting confused and thinking that the slashes were escape sequences.  Could the fact that theres two slashes each place be confusing it by any chance?

Comment: No the 2 back slashes tells it to use a single backslash, but I don't know why it would have a problem with the path of the file.  I haven't seen that before, but if it was having trouble with the string, you could put both into variables to test if that makes a difference.  I would suggest maybe shorten it to something like "C:\\custom.conf" as the argument, since it would cut out the extra folders in the path.  Otherwise, Bearcat did suggest try using StartInfo instead of Start, which lets you set the argument separately.  Definitely an interesting problem.

Comment: Make sure the exe can access the `@"D:\Video Game Emulation\DOS Windows\GAMES\CUSTOM.CONF"` (file and directory). Sounds like the process is being denied access. Note that child processes will not inherit admin permissions from the parent process, so running the exe as admin will not help the child process have admin privs to the directory.